# Как удалить все элементы, идущие после максимального элемента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Необходимо осуществить поиск максимального элемента и затем удалить
все элементы идущие после максимального в двумерном массиве 3x3.

Мой код максимальный элемент находит, но я не знаю как удалить элементы после него:

```
matrix = [
    [3, 7, 5],
    [9, 8, 1],
    [6, 2, 4]
]
 
mx = matrix[0][0]
 
for row in matrix:
    mx_ = max(row)
    if mx_ > mx:
        mx = mx_
```

Что должно получиться в итоге:

```
matrix = [
    [3, 7, 5],
    [9, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```

Comment: что должно быть в итоге? И находит у вас не максимальный элемент, а его значение. Какой именно это элемент неизвестно.

Comment: Максимальный элемент ищется по всей матрице? А элементы удаляются тоже по всей матрице?

Comment: матрица без элементов которые шли после максимального элемента, ну или можно заменить их на 0

Comment: должны удалиться все числа которые идут после максимального числа, по порядку

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ту матрицу, которая должна получиться в результате

Comment: добавил матрицу.

Comment: То есть максимальное число у вас в матрице `8`, а не `9`? Так то в общем понятно теперь более-менее.

Comment: ой. сейчас исправлю

Comment: Вы можете пройти по строкам и столбцам матрицы индексами один раз чтобы определить "координаты" максимального элемента, а второй раз - чтобы заполнить элементы, которые следуют за этими "координатами" нулями. Не используйте `max`, так вы не узнаете нужную "координату". Вернее, её можно будет потом узнать через `index`, можно и так. По-разному можно решать. Я бы предложил вам всё-таки перебирать строки и столбцы по одному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментариях написали уже алгоритм, в коде примерно так можно реализовать, но думаю найдутся и одно двух строчные варианты)

```py
def get_max(matrix):
    max_in_matrix = 0
    for row in matrix:
        max_in_row = max(row)
        if max_in_matrix < max_in_row:
            max_in_matrix = max_in_row
    return max_in_matrix

def reset_next(matrix, max_el):
    next_null = False
    for row in matrix:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if next_null:
                row[i] = 0
            elif row[i] == max_el:
                next_null = True
            continue
    return matrix

max_el = get_max(matrix)
matrix = reset_next(matrix=matrix, max_el=max_el)
```

Comment: А зачем у вас `continue` который ни на что не влияет в данном коде, поскольку расположен в конце цикла? )

Comment: @CrazyElf да, действительно глупость...

Answer (score 4):

```
matrix = [
    [3, 7, 5],
    [9, 8, 1],
    [6, 2, 4]
]

row_with_max = max(matrix, key=lambda x: max(x))  # строка с максимальным значением
i_max = matrix.index(row_with_max)                # индекс строки
j_max = row_with_max.index(max(row_with_max))     # индекс столбца
flat_index = i_max*len(matrix)+j_max              # индекс в плоском списке
```

и "забейте нулями" все, что идет после:

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        if flat_index < i*len(matrix)+j:
            matrix[i][j] = 0
```

теперь в matrix:

```
>>> matrix
[
    [3, 7, 5], 
    [9, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```